# Can't read attributes of nested xml tag (QXmlStreamReader)

Tags: c++, xml, qt, qxmlstreamreader

I have XML file (I had to simplify it):

```
<Line line1_attr1 = "value1" line1_attr2 = "value2">
    <Term line1_term1_attr1 = "term1value1" line1_term1_attr2 = "term1value2">
        term content
    </Term>
    <Term line1_term2_attr1 = "term2value1" line1_term2_attr2 = "term2value2">
        term content
    </Term>
</Line>
<Line line2_attr1 = "value1" line2_attr2 = "value2">
    <Term line2_term1_attr1 = "term1value1" line2_term1_attr2 = "term1value2">
        term content
    </Term>
    <Term line2_term2_attr1 = "term2value1" line2_term2_attr2 = "term2value2">
        term content
    </Term>
</Line>
```

The attributes are stored in two QMaps: `mapString` (attributes for Line) and `MapTerm` (attributes for Term).
I can read the attributes of the `Line` tag but not for the `Term` tag. 
Neither this

```
if(token == QXmlStreamReader::StartElement)
{
    if (xml.name() == "Line")
    {
        QXmlStreamAttributes attrib = xml.attributes();
        for(auto e : mapString->keys())
        {
              mapString->insert(e, attrib.value(e).toString());
        }
        continue;
        if (xml.name() == "Term")
        {
            QXmlStreamAttributes attrib = xml.attributes();
            for(auto e : mapTerm->keys())
            {
                  mapTerm->insert(e, attrib.value(e).toString());
            }
            continue;
        }                  
    }
```

nor

```
if(token == QXmlStreamReader::StartElement)
{
    if (xml.name() == "Line")
    {
        QXmlStreamAttributes attrib = xml.attributes();
        for(auto e : mapString->keys())
        {
              mapString->insert(e, attrib.value(e).toString());
        }
        continue;       
    }
    if (xml.name() == "Term")
    {
        QXmlStreamAttributes attrib = xml.attributes();
        for(auto e : mapTerm->keys())
        {
              mapTerm->insert(e, attrib.value(e).toString());
        }
        continue;
    }
```

is working, the code inside the **if (xml.name() == "Term")** is not executed.

Comment: The first code snippet is obviously wrong, since the second test will never execute - it is dead code. The second snippet works for me as long as it's embedded in a properly designed loop. That is, until you post more complete code that reproduces the problem, I can't tell where the problem is; your second snippet is fine if and only if it's a part of other code that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This loop is more concise and should work:

```
QXmlStreamReader xml;
...
while (!xml.atEnd()) {
  xml.readNext();
  if (xml.isStartElement()) {
    QMap<QString, QString> * map = nullptr;
    if (xml.name() == "Line") map = mapString;
    else if (xml.name() == "Term") map = mapTerm;
    else continue;
    QXmlStreamAttributes attrib = xml.attributes();
    for (auto e : map->keys())
       map->insert(e, attrib.value(e).toString());
  }
}
```